# HtmlAgilityPack Scrape table from website

Tags: vb.net, html-agility-pack

I am learning how to use HtmlAgilityPack and I cannot find any documentation on scraping tables in the way I need.

My table looks like this

```
|     | NAME                                  | PRICE            | TIME      |
| --- | ------------------------------------- | ---------------- | --------- |
|     | Arma 3                                | $29.99           | 1586h 57m |
|     | DayZ                                  | $44.99           | 28h 05m   |
|     | Survarium                             | Free or No Price | 02h 25m   |
|     | Squad                                 | $49.99           | 11h 05m   |
|     | Squad - Public Testing                | Not in store     | 0h 0m     |
|     | Counter-Strike: Global Offensive      | Free or No Price | 00h 26m   |
|     | Infestation: Survivor Stories Classic | Free or No Price | 00h 05m   |
|     | PLAYERUNKNOWN'S BATTLEGROUNDS         | $29.99           | 0h 0m     |
```

I have tried many things found on Google regarding tables and HtmlAgilityPack but none have worked.
I have a listview that I want the data to go into. The only things I want are
`gname`, `gprice`, `gtime` loaded to the listview and remembering that these values change depending on the games listed.

**I can't post what I've already tried as there would be to many website posts to go back through and find.**

The html for the table on the website is this

````
<div class="col-12">
                    <h2>Dan Andrews Steam Profile 8                        Games</h2>
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table game-table">
                            <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th></th>
                                <th class="gname">NAME</th>
                                <th style="width:200px">PRICE</th>
                                <th style="width:200px">TIME</th>
                            </tr>

                                                            <tr>
                                    <td class="gicon"><img src="https://cdn.cloudflare.steamstatic.com/steam/apps/107410/capsule_184x69.jpg" onerror="this.src='/assets/images/applogo.svg'">
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="gname">Arma 3</td>
                                    <td class="gprice">$29.99</td>
                                    <td class="gtime">1586h 57m</td>
                                </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                    <td class="gicon"><img src="https://cdn.cloudflare.steamstatic.com/steam/apps/221100/capsule_184x69.jpg" onerror="this.src='/assets/images/applogo.svg'">
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="gname">DayZ</td>
                                    <td class="gprice">$44.99</td>
                                    <td class="gtime">28h 05m</td>
                                </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                    <td class="gicon"><img src="https://cdn.cloudflare.steamstatic.com/steam/apps/355840/capsule_184x69.jpg" onerror="this.src='/assets/images/applogo.svg'">
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="gname">Survarium</td>
                                    <td class="gprice">Free or No Price</td>
                                    <td class="gtime">02h 25m</td>
                                </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                    <td class="gicon"><img src="https://cdn.cloudflare.steamstatic.com/steam/apps/393380/capsule_184x69.jpg" onerror="this.src='/assets/images/applogo.svg'">
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="gname">Squad</td>
                                    <td class="gprice">$49.99</td>
                                    <td class="gtime">11h 05m</td>
                                </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                    <td class="gicon"><img src="https://cdn.cloudflare.steamstatic.com/steam/apps/774941/capsule_184x69.jpg" onerror="this.src='/assets/images/applogo.svg'">
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="gname">Squad - Public Testing</td>
                                    <td class="gprice">Not in store</td>
                                    <td class="gtime">0h 0m</td>
                                </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                    <td class="gicon"><img src="https://cdn.cloudflare.steamstatic.com/steam/apps/730/capsule_184x69.jpg" onerror="this.src='/assets/images/applogo.svg'">
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="gname">Counter-Strike: Global Offensive</td>
                                    <td class="gprice">Free or No Price</td>
                                    <td class="gtime">00h 26m</td>
                                </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                    <td class="gicon"><img src="https://cdn.cloudflare.steamstatic.com/steam/apps/226700/capsule_184x69.jpg" onerror="this.src='/assets/images/applogo.svg'">
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="gname">Infestation: Survivor Stories Classic</td>
                                    <td class="gprice">Free or No Price</td>
                                    <td class="gtime">00h 05m</td>
                                </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                    <td class="gicon"><img src="https://cdn.cloudflare.steamstatic.com/steam/apps/578080/capsule_184x69.jpg" onerror="this.src='/assets/images/applogo.svg'">
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="gname">PLAYERUNKNOWN'S BATTLEGROUNDS</td>
                                    <td class="gprice">$29.99</td>
                                    <td class="gtime">0h 0m</td>
                                </tr>
                                                        </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution in C# (even though the question is tagged with VB.Net). You get a list of Game objects here. And you can then bind these to a ListView or whatever you may need.

```
    public class Game
    {
        public string Img { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double? Price { get; set; }
        public string? PriceStatus { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan? Time { get; set; }
    }

    public static void Go()
    {
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(File.ReadAllText(htmlFilePath));

        Regex timeRegex = new Regex(@"\b(\d+)h\b\s*\b(\d+)m\b", RegexOptions.Compiled);
        Regex priceRegex = new Regex(@"\b\$?(\d+\.\d\d)\b", RegexOptions.Compiled);

        List<Game> gamesList =
            doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@class='table game-table']/tbody/tr")
                .Select(tr => tr.SelectNodes("td")?.ToList())
                .Where(tds => tds != null && tds.Any())
                .Select(
                    (tds) =>
                    {
                        return
                            new
                            {
                                Img = tds[0].SelectSingleNode("img").Attributes["src"].Value,
                                Name = tds[1].InnerText,
                                PriceString = tds[2].InnerText,
                                PriceMatch = priceRegex.Match(tds[2].InnerText),
                                TimeString = tds[3].InnerText,
                                TimeMatch = timeRegex.Match(tds[3].InnerText),
                            };
                    })
                .Select(
                    (v) =>
                    {
                        Game game =
                            new Game
                            {
                                Img = v.Img,
                                Name = v.Name,
                            };

                        //Set Price
                        if (v.PriceMatch.Success)
                        {
                            game.Price = double.Parse(v.PriceMatch.Groups[1].Value);
                            game.PriceStatus = "In Store";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            game.PriceStatus = v.PriceString;
                        }

                        //Set Time
                        if (v.TimeMatch.Success)
                        {
                            int hours = int.Parse(v.TimeMatch.Groups[1].Value);
                            int minutes = int.Parse(v.TimeMatch.Groups[2].Value);

                            game.Time = new TimeSpan(hours, minutes, 0);
                        }

                        return game;
                    })
                .ToList();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and I am also sorry it has taken so long to reply. This is however in C# as you mentioned, but I am still learning and have no idea how to convert to vb.net without error.